# Rules for locating header files

Tags: c, compiler-construction, header-files, include-path

When you write `#include "foo.h"` I would expect the compiler to check the directory of the file doing the including (as opposed to the current directory) first, and if not found there then fall back on a search of the list of paths as in the case of `#include <foo.h>`.

Unless an absolute path was specified, `#include "/foo.h"`, in which case only the absolute path needs to be checked.

Are there any C compilers where the rules are different?

Comment: i am using gcc but the rules are same which you have listed..! i think including such files are part of c-language stuff isnt it?

Comment: Oddly enough no, the language spec says it's implementation defined. That's why I want to check if any implementations do otherwise.

Comment: oh then +1 to you...may be some cross-compilation tool chain do in some other way..!! o/w gcc ,sun studio,visual studio,turbo's compiler, all follow this rules.

Comment: The standard cannot define how to search directories, as that would limit the implementation to systems that actually *have* directories in their file system. Or have a file system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernighan & Ritchie write:

> [#include "foo"] searches first in association with the original source file (a deliberately implementation-dependent phrase), and if that search fails, then as in the first form.

Which means, make no assumption on the search strategy for quotes. However, all compilers I have run into share the praxis of searching in the including file's path first, and falling back to the compiler's search path if not found.